# How to store the image in Parse local data store in offline mode

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-imageview, local-datastore

I have been searching for storing the image offline using:

```
Bitmap image = ...
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("image.png", data);
file.saveInBackground();

photo = new Photo();
photo.setPhotoFile(file);
photo.pinInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
   @Override
   public void done(ParseException e) {
      if (e == null) {
        Log.d("SAVED", "SAVED SUCCESSFULLY");
      } else {
        Log.d("ERROR msg is :", e.getMessage());
      }
 });
```

This gives error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to encode an unsaved ParseFile.

But when I use "photo.saveInBackground" it works. I have searched on the Google but can't find the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

The method `file.saveInBackground();` is asynchronous. You should either call `file.save();` or implement callback to pin the `photo` once the `file` is saved.